# unable to find operating system

Tags: boot

I just rebooted my server after a few updates i get with the `apt update && apt upgrade` command and now the message 'unable to find operating system' or something in that direction, after the BIOS is done. I tried boot-repair but that says that it can't find the hard drives and I am also doubting this is the right form to ask this in but it did happen after I updated my ubuntu server. Anyone has a clue what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Update from which version to version and how was the upgrade done (on-premise or remote)?

Comment: When are you seeing this message? After the BIOS or grub ( I assume grub)? Did you do a kernel update?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen not version update should have added that, just a `apt update && apt upgrade`
@pdf4664 after BIOS

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not have a "let's hide the hard drives from BIOS" feature. Who would want that?

Boot from a LiveUSB and run a [SMART test](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en) on your storage.

If the drives are still undetectable, then you seem to have a hardware (drive, motherboard, cable, or power supply) fault that is outside the scope of Ubuntu support (sorry).

Comment: yeah that seems obvious to me bu before the bios is done it does detect them and a co-worker had a tool so now we are in a safe mode environment and the drives are accesable and nothing seems corrupt at least for now